# SNMP OUTPUT OPTIONS - How do I get the OID response value only?

Tags: mysql, bash, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I have to go through and collect a few OIDs from some SNMP enabled network printers with a BASH script I have been working on.

My Request:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.0.77 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2
```

My Actual Response:

```
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 = Counter32: 1974 
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 = Counter32: 633940
```

The Desired Response:

```
1974
633940314
```

(just the oid values only)

I looked and tested several options using the resource from the site below:

http://www.netsnmp.org/docs/man/snmpcmd.html#lbAF

`-Oq` removes '=' so running

```
snmpget -v2c -c public -Oq 10.15.105.133
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2
```

returns

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 Counter32: 1974
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2 Counter 32: 633940314
```

so I know I am phrasing my request properly.

I am taking the values and writing them to a MYSQL dB, I set the data types in my tale schema, the request is consistent so I know the definition of the OID, so I do not need all the information I am getting back, just the value of the OID itself, so I can write it to my dB without manipulating the the response. I probably can manipulate the response pulling the information to the right of ":" and writing the value of the OID.

I am relatively new to SNMP (http://www.net-snmp.org/), but I can not see why this is not a more commonly asked question because I have been searching everywhere for an answer and this post is my last recourse...

Comment: Did you drop a few digits from the "actual response" in your example?  It doesn't match up with the rest of the discussion.

Comment: Not sure this is a Programming Question. One of the answers is a programming answer, though. =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can tune the output with the `-O` argument:

```
snmpgetnext -Oqv -v 2c -c public 192.168.0.77 .1
2
```

See the `--help`:

```
q:  quick print for easier parsing
v:  print values only (not OID = value)
```

Comment: To me this is what Stackoverflow is all about; a succint answer to a specific question.  `-Oqv` is gold.

Answer (score 0):

You can postprocess the output with a simple Awk or `sed` script, or even just `grep` (provided you have `grep -P`).

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.0.77 <<'____HERE' | awk '{ print $4 }'
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2
____HERE
```

or

```
.... | sed 's/.*: //'
```

or

```
.... | grep -oP ':\K[0-9]+'
```