# Strange PHP Output will be created

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents, snmp, fileoutputstream

Whenever I execute my PHP script, I get a strange output: Output: 36, but I only want to have the 36 in FIle and not the string "Output". My script:

```
<?php

$cursyshdd1 = snmpget("192.168.0.100", "public", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.6574.2.1.1.6.0");

$file = 'test.txt';
// Öffnet die Datei, um den vorhandenen Inhalt zu laden
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Fügt eine neue Person zur Datei hinzu
$current .= $cursyshdd1;
// Schreibt den Inhalt in die Datei zurück
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: What does `$cursyshdd1` contain?

Comment: Hi, you need to configure the output of snmpget. This has been answered already here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387400/11201545